# Uploading Video on Twitter

Tags: android, twitter, twitpic

I am new to Twitter Integration with my Android Apps. I have to post Image and Video on Twitter. I am successfully able to post Image on Twitter using Twitpic, but have not found any clue for posting Video on the Twitter.

Please help me, with a relevant link or suggest me a method to do the same.

Sry for asking such a direct question without any piece of code..

Comment: hello @gaurav Arora i want tweet image give idea or code to done task thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can upload media in TwitPic. This code is for image but in same manner you can upload video as well.

```
 class ImageSender extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
    private String url;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SendImageActivity.this, "", "Sending image...", true);

        //mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        //mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {            
        long result = 0;

   //     TwitterSession twitterSession = new TwitterSession(SendImageActivity.this);            
        AccessToken accessToken         = getAccessToken();

        Configuration conf = new ConfigurationBuilder()                 
        .setOAuthConsumerKey(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY) 
        .setOAuthConsumerSecret(Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET) 
        .setOAuthAccessToken(mToken) 
        .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(mSecreat) 
        .build(); 

        OAuthAuthorization auth = new OAuthAuthorization (conf, conf.getOAuthConsumerKey (), conf.getOAuthConsumerSecret (),
                new AccessToken (conf.getOAuthAccessToken (), conf.getOAuthAccessTokenSecret ()));

        ImageUpload upload = ImageUpload.getTwitpicUploader ("8d012dd3948af2cdc42f93859908a717", auth);

        Log.d(TAG, "Start sending image...");

        try {
            url = upload.upload(new File(imagePath));
            result = 1;

            Log.d(TAG, "Image uploaded, Twitpic url is " + url);            
        } catch (Exception e) {        
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to send image");

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {            
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        //mProgressDialog.cancel();

        String text = (result == 1) ? "Image sent successfully.\n Twitpic url is: " + url : "Failed to send image";
        System.out.println("Twitter Image==========="+text);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
} 

  public AccessToken getAccessToken() {
    String token        = mToken;
    String tokenSecret  = mSecreat;

    if (token != null && tokenSecret != null) 
        return new AccessToken(token, tokenSecret);
    else
        return null;
}
```

Don't forgot to do login code first and using libraries(jars).

Comment: ,i add jar file but not gettting getTwitpicUploader.

Comment: @dipali was just busy !!! Following are the libraries which I used for twitter :  1.twitpic4j    2.twitter4j-core-3.0.3    3.twitter4j-media-support-3.0.3